# session_id() creates new session every reload

Tags: php, session

I've read this before:

[How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

I have a session page, when I refresh/reload it, it creates a new session id!

All my codes :

```
<?php   
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION['test'])){
        $_SESSION['test'] = session_id();   
    }   
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

but when I refresh my page, it creates a new session id ! why?

Comment: Can you show us some values for your `session.*` variables in the server's `php.ini`?

Comment: Does output buffering interrupt normal transmission of session data to the browser?

Comment: try `ob_start();` after the `session_start`

Comment: @Sebas I changed it but unchanged...